# Forward Java jar display to another computer

Tags: ssh, java, x11-forwarding

I have a web server, using X11 forwarding, that I `ssh -Y` into in order to activate a Rails app. The app contains a system call to a jar file which will display on my computer:

```
def executeJar
    value = %x( {PATH TO JAVA} -jar {PATH TO JAR} )
end
```

and I call this link using a simple `link_to` tag in html.erb.

My problem is that the the GUI is appearing only on my screen, rather than on others as I would like.  (I.e., if someone on another computer clicks the link, the GUI will appear on my screen, rather than theirs.)

Is there anything I can do about this to change where the GUI appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very unusual, as web applications usually do not interact with X11.

If you look at the incoming IP address, you may be able to set the `$DISPLAY` environment variable to `<client IP address>:0` and then run the Java program as before.

But this assumes several things:

1. The web client is not behind a firewall that would block TCP on port 6000 (or 6000 plus the display number).
2. That display `0` is the correct one.  (Usually true, but not always.)
3. The web client is running X11 and has it configured to accept connections from your server.  This will not be true generally.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It might be better to pursue a different approach, but I will try your suggestions.  Only a handful of systems will actually access the jar.